# Basic ng-if is not working

Tags: angular

Even if the condition is false but it is still entering into it.

```html
    <div 
      ng-if="1==2">
      Checking
    </div>
```

Comment: Please read at least some introductorial tutorials before asking questions - like https://angular.io

Comment: Thanks buddy. I know it was a very basic question but somehow I got stuck there.

Answer (score 3):

Correct syntax for `NgIf` directive in Angular 2 is:

```
<div *ngIf="1 == 2">
    Checking
</div>
```

Read more about `NgIf` directive [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html).

Comment: Thanks a not dear.

Comment: But can you tell me why the compiler didn't generate error for my wrong syntax.

Comment: @ahsannaeem By its very nature, HTML is extensible. You could put `cats="9"` on a tag, and the compiler wouldn't care. Angular is only interested in inputs `[cats]="9", outputs `(cats)="countMyCats($event);"`, and user-defined directives. In your case, the compiler glanced at `ng-if`, saw that it was none of those three things, and moved on without errors. Hope that helps!

Comment: why was this voted down? It's a legit question IMHO. Regardless, here is a quick reference ( https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference#ng-if ) . Angular 1 is on the left and angular 2 is on the right

Answer (score 2):

There is no `ng-if` in Angular2

It should be

```
<div 
  *ngIf="1==2">
  Checking
</div>
```

Ensure you have `BrowserModule` (in `AppModule`) or `CommonModule` in other modules in

```
imports: [BrowserModule]
```